# Spring Annotation Configuration Not Starting

Tags: spring, tomcat

I have a Spring MVC application which I I deploy on a tomcat server. It worked fine, until I was told to use an annotation configuration, rather than a web.xml file.

I've added a logger to my intialiser, and it doesn't even seem to be starting, and the pages are now just giving me 404 errors.

This is my initialiser class

```
package com.demo.web.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;


public class ImpInitialiser implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);
    Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    dynamic.addMapping("/");
    dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
}
```

}

And here is my Config class.

```
package com.demo.web.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.demo.web")
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

}

[Edit]
I've simplified the code from the original post, just to try and get any example working.

Is there anything obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: are you in a servlet 3.0+ environment ?

Comment: Yes. My application worked fine when I was using a web.xml and dispacher-servlet.xml file.

Comment: Can you share your tomcat version ? Apache Tomcat maps its internal DefaultServlet to "/", and on Tomcat versions <= 7.0.14, this servlet mapping cannot be overridden programmatically. 7.0.15 fixes this issue.

Comment: Also, have you deleted `web.xml`? If not, `WebInitialiser` will not get called

Comment: I have, there's no xml files in the project now. Also, I'm using 7.0.53

Comment: Don't extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` instead. Also why are you loading your configuration twice? Both the `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` load the same configuration absically duplicating everything.  Why is there a `@Resource` on your bean method, that shouldn't be there. Check your `catalina.out` for more information on what is happening. Also I suggest setting spring logging to DEBUG or TRACE. Make sure that you don't have any servlet related classes in your WEB-INF/lib (like a `servlet-api.jar`).

Comment: I've removed the resource field, and made sure I'm loading the configuration only once now. Still exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One**:

```
// Create the 'root' Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
        new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);
```

I think is wrong, there you must register the **server** beans, not the web beans

The following is correct

```
// Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext =
        new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);
```

Because `DispatcherConfig` represent your **Web** infrastructure configuration.

You are registering `DispatcherConfig.class` twice and I think is **not** correct.
Has no sense, first time I see that approach.

**Two:**

```
@Bean
@Resource(name = "jdbc/testDB")
public DataSource dataSourceLookup() {
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/testDB");
    return dataSource;
}
```

Declare a `DataSource` in the *web* side is a bad practice.

**Three:**

Post your `@Controller` class.

**Four:**

I think is not neccessary

`registry.addViewController("/grouporroles").setViewName("grouporroles");`

because you are scanning the `@Controller`s through `@ComponentScan("com.demo.web.controller")`

**Five**

Change:

```
@Bean
@Resource(name = "jdbc/testDB")
public DataSource dataSourceLookup() {
```

to

```
@Bean(name = "jdbc/testDB")
public DataSource dataSourceLookup() {
```

Comment: I've edited the code to make it much simpler. Right now I'm just trying to get any simple example working.

Comment: Check *Five* section added.